# dockerode, how make the process running in container independent from the node process?

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm working on a small app utilising `dockerode` for the container management. I'm trying to make the process running in the docker container independent from `node` process.

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is if the node process crashes after restarting it can reattach back to the running container and continue as if nothing happened.

The issue I run into even though the container itself is independent from  node the process inside the container isn't, if the node is killed so is the process in docker container. Is there a way to detach a process in container from node process?

The functions to create container and reattach to it are as follows:

```
function createContainer() {
    docker.createContainer({
        Image: 'ubuntu',
        Tty: true,
        Cmd: ['/bin/bash']
    }, function (err, container) {
        if (err) return;

        container.start({}, function (err, data) {
            const stream = fs.createWriteStream('./containerID.json');
            stream.write(JSON.stringify({
                containerID: container.id
            }));

            shell.exec(`docker cp ./script.sh ${container.id}:/`) // copy the file to the container

            runExec(container);
        });
    });
}
```

---

```
exports.containerAttach = (container) => {
    container.attach({
        stream: true,
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true
    }, function (err, stream) {
        stream.pipe(process.stdout);
    })
}
```

Comment: The usual answer is to launch a single long-running container separately from the front-end script, and make network requests to it using HTTP or something similar.  Using `shell.exec("docker ...")` is rather scary from a security perspective; in your example if it can ever happen that `container.id` has punctuation, this can easily be used to take over the entire host system.

Comment: My example is just me fiddling with the concept. In actuality the front-end and back-end are two separate APIs. The container is created from back-end using `dockerode`. But from what I'm seeing the process in the container is dependent on the process that spawned it, in this case node back-end. So if I kill the node process, even though the container remains, the process inside it is dead, I'm trying to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: After some digging it seems I need to run the `docker exec -d <container id>` as suggested [here](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/issues/106). My [`runExec()`](https://pastebin.com/FNyGvXYx) follows the example he provided in the end, but do I make it run in detached mode?

Comment: `docker exec` is not intended to be used this way.  You say the two separate containers have APIs; why can’t you make an ordinary HTTP call to the back-end API?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm saying front-end is it's own API, which interfaces with back-end(contains dockerode code) to create and run a container. The font-end doesn't have direct access to dockerode. I'm trying to make process in docker container run independently from back-end. If the back-end dies, the process in the container isn't effected,  so far `docker exec -d ...` seems to be the best option for this, but what's the equivalent in JS?

Comment: Never mine, I was wrong about the whole thing. The process stays running in container in background, confirmed by `htop`, even after killing the node process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container was initially created with idle BASH shell.

```
docker.createContainer({
        Image: 'ubuntu',
        Tty: true,
        Cmd: ['/bin/bash']
    },...)
```

When the attach function ran, it attached to this idle TTY. The solution was to switch to `docker.run()` and then attach to the running process.

```
docker.run('node', ['./home/run-in-container.sh'], false, {
        Hostconfig: {
            Binds: [`${__dirname}:/home`]
        }
    }, {}, (err, data, container) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data.StatusCode)
        console.log(container)
    })
    .on('container', (container) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'container.json'), JSON.stringify({
                id: container.id
            }));
            process.exit(0);
        }, 5000)
    })
    .on('stream', (stream) => {
        stream.on('data', data => console.log('-- STREAM --\n', data.toString()));
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('data', data);
    });
```

The attach function remained mostly the same, but slightly modified to match the new run function.

```
container.attach({
        stream: true,
        stderr: true,
        stdout: true
    }, (err, stream) => {
        if (err) console.log(`The container has ${container.id} been removed:\n\n${err}`);
        console.log(`Reattached to container: ${container.id}`);

        stream.on('data', (data) => console.log('-- STREAM --\n', data.toString()));
        stream.on('end', () => {
            console.log('\n-- STREAM END --')
        });
    });
```